# Have transferred all music to SD card but still seem to have full system/ user data

Tags: internal-storage

My galaxy S7 external SD card seemed to have stopped working. Which caused my phone to show full internal storage. I replaced the SD card with a new and larger one and transferred all my google play music to it. My phone is still showing full storage. 30.5 GB of storage is consumed by userdata/system. I removed the external sd card and checked if the google play music was showing any data still. No data is showing. So I can not for the life of me figure out what data and where is consuming all my storage.

Next step is clear the cache.

Last step is master/hard reset. Really don't feel like that though.

Ideas?

Comment: And clearing cache did nothing.

Comment: So I figured I would just start throwing things at the wall. I ran a graphics test in recovery mode. Then went back in to settings>device maintenance>storage>update and ran a 360 security database update. Then wettings>device maintenance>storage settings>phone memory. Interestingly is showed my music and audio to be the main culprit. I selected it and it opened my google play music app. Verified that it still was set to external storage and then went back in to my settings>device maintenance>storage and lo and behold my storage dropped from 31.5 GB used to 18GB used.

Comment: My assumption is that even though google play music app had transferred the files to my sd card it still retained the files in some hidden directory. By running the security database update it must have recognized the files and deleted them from the internal storage. That or my phone was drunk and needed to sober up and realize the files were transferred.

Comment: You can self answer the question too, to help others in a similar situation :)